# call UIView in Array to UITableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, nsarray

I have built a UIView with some stuff like buttons and labels on it. I was wondering how I could assign that UIView a string value so that it could be added to the NSArray that holds the titles for the other cells. The end result would have the first cell showing the UIView and the subsequent cells holding the title values. This would alleviate the need for a UIScrollView and UITableView on a single ViewController. I'll try to pseudo it here:

METHOD
UIView with buttons, labels, etc.

METHOD
Create UITableView and assign the cell titles the strings in the ARRAY

ARRAY
Here are my cell titles

Target: add a string identifier for the UIView into the Array so that the first cell is the UIView that I have setup followed by the cells that are titled with the ARRAY.

```
self.array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: @"string for my UIVIEW??", @"one title", @"two title", nil];
```

Thanks.